# How to replace variables with functions in an expression?

Tags: rule

I have an expression:

```
KK = -(2*b *(c + 6) *(b + a) *d /(b + d) *(c + d))
```

`a`, `b`, `c`, `d` - are variables,

`a[i_]:=i^2;` `b[i_]:=i;` `c[i_]:=i-2;` `d[i_]:=i^3;` - are functions.

I would like to change the variables to the functions in this way:

```
a -> a[i_], b -> b[i_], c -> c[i_], d -> d[i_].
```

How can this be done?

Comment: `KK /. {a -> a[i], b -> b[i], c -> c[i], d -> d[i]}` ?

Comment: I request you to format your questions properly. In this case, add code blocks and use relevant tags. You have been around long enough.

Comment: @Syed, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

KK = -(2*b*(c + 6)*(b + a)*d/(b + d)*(c + d));

KK2 = KK /. (# :> #[i] & /@ Variables[Level[KK, {-1}]])

(* -((2 b[i] (a[i] + b[i]) (6 + c[i]) d[i] (c[i] + d[i]))/(b[i] + d[i])) *)
```